# What is the difference between declaring an explicit generic parameter and use a constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Which is the difference between doing this:

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>
        (this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        return !dictionary.ContainsKey(key) || 
           dictionary.ContainsKey(key) && dictionary[key].Count == 0;
    }
```

And this:

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>
        (this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
         where TValue : List<TValue>
    {
        return !dictionary.ContainsKey(key) || 
           dictionary.ContainsKey(key) && dictionary[key].Count == 0;
    }
```

As far as I can notice, the compiler doesn't tell me that there isn't anything wrong. But, is this any approach better than the other? Will it have any different return value (because I don't realize about this yet)?

Comment: Does that work? I don't see how a type can be a constrained to a list of said type, but I'm not well versed in generic constraints.

Comment: A constraint simply restricts a type to one that has a specific implementation (like an interface or base class). You should first try both of the above and see what happens. :)

Comment: @RufusL is absolutely right; the difference between your two code samples is that the first one works and the second one does not!  The compiler will not give you an error at the declaration site, but when you try to actually call the function, you'll find that the second one does not work at all.  Suppose you try to call your function with `List<int>` for `TValue`.  Since `List<int>` is not a `List<List<int>>`, it will not work. Suppose you try to call your function with `int` for `TValue`; well, `int` is not `List<int>`, so that also fails.

Comment: There are *rare and bizarre* situations where that kind of constraint works, and you should avoid those rare and bizarre situations. For more thoughts on this pattern and why it is a bad idea, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/

Comment: Also, there's no need to ever write `!A || A && B`.  Just write `!A || B`. If !A is true then we don't evaluate A&&B, and if !A is false then A&&B is true&&B which is just B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: your best bet for answering this question yourself would have been *try it*.  You would have soon seen that when you attempted to call the function in its second form, it does not work.

That said, let's dig into this a bit.  We have

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> dictionary, TKey key)
```

versus

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
  where TValue : List<TValue>
```

Why is the second one wrong? Well, what type argument would you like to pass for `TValue`?  Suppose we have a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` in hand. What is the `TValue` we can use?  It's not `int`, because that doesn't meet the constraint: `int` does not derive from `List<int>`.  But it is not `List<int>` either because `List<int>>` does not derive from `List<TValue>`, which is `List<List<int>>`.

So, now we know why the second one is wrong.  Let's now answer more questions:

> Under what circumstances does this sort of "recursive" constraint make sense?

Suppose we are trying to find the *maximum* key in a dictionary:

```
public static TKey MaxKey<TKey, TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
  where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
  if (dictionary.Count == 0) throw ...
  TKey best = default(TKey);
  bool first = true;
  foreach(TKey k in dictionary.Keys)
  {
    if (first || best.CompareTo(k) < 0)
      best = k;
    first = false;
  }
  return best;
}
```

Here it totally makes sense to constrain `TKey` to `IComparable<TKey>`; we're going to compare keys.

> What are some other ways that people use and misuse this pattern?

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/ for many examples.

> Why is the first method less than perfect?

Because it does not handle these two cases:

First, suppose we have a multidictionary but it is not from keys to lists:

```
Dictionary<string, int[]>
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, Stack<int>>
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>
```

or whatever.

Second, it also does not handle the case

```
class MyList : List<int> {}
...
Dictionary<string, MyList>
```

though that case is pretty rare; you ought not to be extending `List<T>` normally.

> What is the right way to implement my dictionary method for maximum generality?

Here's one way:

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this IEnumerable items)
{
  // EXERCISE: Why is this implementation bad? 
  // EXERCISE: Can you improve it?
  foreach(var item in items)
    return false;
  return true;
}

public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>(
  this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) 
  where TValue : IEnumerable
{
  return !dictionary.ContainsKey(key) || dictionary[key].IsEmpty();
}
```

For even more generality you might use `IDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: That implementation of `IsEmpty()` is virtually identical to the implementation of `Enumerable.Any()`, so it can only be improved very marginally.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Sure, but we can avoid a number of unnecessary costs. Remember, we're working with `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` which means that we are possibly taking on an unnecessary boxing penalty and the collection pressure that comes with it.